# Structure for a basic follow/unfollow system in PHP

Tags: php, database

can anybody show me a basic mysqli/php structure for a follow unfollow system? I want to know the table structure and what query would be used to follow/unfollow a user.

Thanks!

Comment: heavily complicated system for a quick answer.

Comment: I already have a bunch of systems (users, sessions, messages, etc.) running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your mysql database 
First create a table of users
Then a table of relations with fields like userid (Foreign key) follow/unfollow flag, another userid (foreign key)

Comment: To save the relations between your users create a table of relationship in mysql with 2 main columns for exemple : FOLLOWER AND FOLLOWED in each column insert the userIds

Comment: If you are developping a social network use http://www.neo4j.org/ instead of mysql